# How to insert a byte array with SqlKata?

Tags: arrays, byte, varbinary, sqlkata

I'm using the last stable version of SqlKata (1.1.7) and I want to insert a new row in a SqlServer table.

My actual code is:

```cs
queryFactory.Query("MyTable").Insert(new
            {
                MESSAGGIO = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(messaggio.Messaggio),
                MITTENTE = messaggio.Mittente,
                TIPO_MITTENTE = messaggio.TipoMittente,
                DESTINATARIO = messaggio.Destinatario,
                TIPO_DESTINATARIO = messaggio.TipoDestinatario,
                DATA_MESSAGGIO = DateTime.Now
            })
```

This code generate an insert query with (5 + ByteArray size) parameters and obviously the sqlserver generates the error of incorrect number of parameters into the insert statement.
There is a way to resolve this problem in SqlKata?

Comment: I think this issues is solved in the latest prerelease https://www.nuget.org/packages/SqlKata/1.1.8-ci-712